# How to declare member variable of subclass in Theos

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos, tweak, member-variables

For example, when I declare subclass of existing class,
I can write as below in theos:

```
%subclass NEWCLASS: EXISTINGCLASS
- (void)overridemethod {
//code
}

%new(v@:)
- (void)newmethod {
//code
}
%end
```

But I don't know how to declare member or property variables of new class...

<s>What should I do?</s>

OK, I got it.

---

But there are errors when I compile package..

I wrote code as below:

```
%subclass SBIconSubClass: SBIcon

%new
- (NSString *)aString {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(aString));
}

%new
- (void)setAString:(NSString *)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(aString), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)application {
    self.aString = @"Test";
    NSLog(@"%@",self.aString);

    return %orig;
}

%end
```

and error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, `ivars` are not supported.
What you can do is simulate properties, using `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject`.

```
%new
- (BOOL)boolProp {
    NSNumber * _boolProp = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(boolProp));
    return _boolProp ? [_boolProp boolValue] : NO;
}

%new
- (NSString *)aString {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(aString));
}

%new
- (void)setBoolProp:(BOOL)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(boolProp), @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

%new
- (void)setAString:(NSString *)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(aString), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

This way you can access `boolProp` and `aString` as a properties:

```
inst.boolProp = YES;
if (inst.boolProp) {
    ...
}

inst.aString = @"Hello";
```

In your example you also need to define an interface:

```
@interface SBIconSubClass
    - (NSString *)aString;
    - (void)setAString:(NSString *)value;
@end
```